# Python, Selenium, download all MIME types

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download some files using selenium webdriver for Firefox.
How to set option `browser.helperApps.neverAsk` for any MIME type?

Now this option working only for `application/pdf` (in my script):

```
#selenium profile
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', download_dir)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf')
#-------------------
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to list the mimetypes explicitly and separate the values with commas:

```
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',
                       'application/pdf,text/csv')
```

Comment: Checking FF's source code shows that it [searches the specific download's content type inside the pref string](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/4ccefc3181f9d237ef4ca8bd17b4e7c101ddf7b5/uriloader/exthandler/nsExternalHelperAppService.cpp#2426). So indeed, only exact matches would work.